# iPhone X Bottom Speakers Not Working?

Tags: iphone, audio, speakers

I recently got an iPhone X and noticed it has the same issues with its speakers at the bottom of the device as my older iPhone 5s.

On both sides of the charging port there are grills for the speakers, however there is no audio coming from the left one. When I place my finger over the right, I can feel it but not on the left.

Since this was on both iPhone X and 5s, I have to wonder if this is poor design or by dumb luck, they both have the same fault. Since my futile attempts at finding anything on this have come up short, could someone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may look like both are speakers, but in fact the speakers on the iPhone are top centre & bottom right - you get the best stereo impression with the phone in landscape orientation.

Pic from Apple -

[image]

Rather more blatant pic from youtube...

[image]